# Is it possible to use Mockito with Kotlin without open the class?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, kotlin

As we probably know, by default Kotlin class once defined, it is final, unless it is explicitly declared `open`.

This would post a challenge when we want to Mock it using Mockito. We need to explicitly declare it as `open`. Is there a way we could avoid declaring it as `open` while able to Mock it for our testing?

Comment: You could make it implement an interface and mock that instead.

Comment: Thanks @AndroidEx. If you could elaborate and provide an working example of that, that would really help. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin

Comment: There is another easy solution for mockito for mocking final classes, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39367070/3679676

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mockito2](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2) can now mock final classes as well.

However, this feature is **opt-in**, so you need to enable it manually.
To do so, you need to define a file `/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing the line `mock-maker-inline`

See e.g.
http://hadihariri.com/2016/10/04/Mocking-Kotlin-With-Mockito/ or 
 https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable
for a quick introduction

on a side note, this currently [doesn't work for android](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/648#issuecomment-321699294)

Comment: Is it working with dexmaker? For Android Instrumentation tests?

Comment: @folkyatina no idea, sorry

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, and is apparently not supported for Android: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/648

Comment: @amitav13 yeah unfortunately. however, the question is not tagged `android`. but I'll update the answer to make this more clear

Comment: For Android Instrumentation tests we can use [dexopener](https://github.com/tmurakami/dexopener), which opens final classes without necessity to modify them or add annotations.

Answer (score 11):

The MockMaker plugin doesn't seem to work when running espresso tests. Therefore, you can use Kotlin's [all-open pugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin) instead.

Add the plugin in build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"
```

Specify the annotation that will make the class open:

```
allOpen {
    annotation("com.my.MyMockable")
}
```

Create your annotation which can be used to annotate classes:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class MyMockable
```

Then, in order to make your class and its public methods Mockable (open), annotate it with your annotation:

```
@MyMockable
```

Comment: I liked this solution for being the least intrusive and the one that offers most control over the alternatives.

Answer (score 8):

There're three ways I'm aware of how you can mock Kotlin classes:

1. Use interfaces instead of classes. In this case you replace all usages of a particular class with the corresponding interface. And in testing code you mock the interface.

   ```
   interface Something { /* ... */ }

   class SomethingImpl : Something { /* ... */ }

   fun processSomething(something: Something) { /* ... */ }

   val something = mock(Something::class.java)
   processSomething(mock)
   ```
2. Make classes open, which is not very convenient.
3. Use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) instead of Mockito. Using its `ClassLoader` you can do much more than with Mockito.

I prefer the first approach because it's a good idea to work with interfaces instead of classes even if you don't use mocking frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Michael. So for every class we need to test, we need to implement an interface instead? That sounds like more code change than 'open' the class, Or did I miss something...

Comment: Sure, but it's a big step towards a better architecture :)

Comment: Creating a separate interface without a valid reason (from an OO or API design standpoint) is over-enginneering as it only adds complexity. It's even worse than making a class unnecessarily `open`. (And, no, not creating the interface does *not* violate GoF´s principle of "program to an interface, not an implementation".)

Comment: The question is too general to have a single correct answer, but in my opinion classes that need to be mocked are usually injected as dependencies and have other dependencies injected into them. In this case creating a separate interface for such classes is a good idea as it helps to make the system loosely coupled and unit testing easier or even possible. That's quite a valid reason for me.

Comment: It's getting a bit off-topic but wanted to point out that using interfaces does not necessarily reduce coupling. You always rely on the contract. If you simply move all public methods to an interface, you do not affect coupling, you just make more code lines. A class has an interface + implementation but when you pass an object around, it's just the interface (_the contract_) that everything relies on.

Comment: There is another option: You can use [all-open compiler plugin from kotlin](https://engineering.21buttons.com/mocking-kotlin-classes-with-mockito-the-fast-way-631824edd5ba) in your test builds.